# Unexpected padding html document, from window top border in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

this is my entire html document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin-left: 0px;
            margin-top: 0px;
            background-color: #0ff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-color: #090">some text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In google chrome, div tag is padding of window top border, somewhere 20-25px, in other browsers, all good, no top padding for div tag. someone know why is this problem in chrome?

Comment: have you tried `html, body { padding: 0; margin:0; }`

Comment: I trying:     html, body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: #0ff;
    padding: 0; margin: 0; 
   }


not working

Comment: The padding doesn't appear in my browser either. What version of Chrome are you using? Also, can you create a fiddle to demonstrate the problem (http://jsfiddle.net/, be aware that a reset is applied by default when the "Normalized CSS" checkbox is checked).

Answer (score 3):

Always use reset styles when you're making applications cross-browsers, in this way you can fix all the inconsistencies easily, you can try something basic like:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Or use some other "more complete" solutions like the ones here:

- [Eric Meyer's Reset Styles](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html)
- [YUI Reset Styles](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/)

For example `Eric Meyer’s Reset Styles` tell us to use:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Overly simplistic resets are a bad idea, and should be avoided at all costs. For example, consider a CMS where the end user enters HTML through a WYSIWYG editor. The above CSS resets remove the margin and padding from UL and LI elements. This makes the "Bullet list" display the bullets to the left and outside of the content area.

Comment: I was only using a part of the full reset, check the update and it's the full `css`, ol, ul {list-style: none;} fix the "bullet list" display. Reset is used if you want more consistency cross-browsers is like using a white new paper for making a draw instead of a paper with some erased draws on it.

Comment: My point about the bullets still stands… When the end user hits the "Bullet list" button in the WYSIWYG editor, they expect the bullets to appear and be styled appropriately. Making them disappear with `list-style: none;` leads to calls from clients about a "broken website". If you're going to use a reset to make your styling easier, you need to add basic styles back in for editable content. Alternatively, look into using SCSS and `@extend` to create minimal resets for oft used paradigms. For example, here's one I use myself: http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/mQjJb/